# Glassfish App deployed successfully but 404 not found and Web Services not accessible

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, payara

I am trying to deploy a web application. Iam using the latest Payara 4.1.1.154 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 and by using Netbeans 8.1 as my IDE.

I have tried the deployment both from Netbeans and from the terminal with the `asadmin deploy` command.

While the deployment is successful according to the log file, the resources are inaccessible. I get no errors-exception during the deployment. Nothing, everything is clear.
However, i get a "404 not found" in my index page and my REST services are inaccessible too.

Here is a snapshot with my current folder structure and configuration

[image: Current project folder structure and xml files context, web and glassfish-web]

Comment: Which URL do you use? Have a look at the last lines of the log during deployment to see at which context root the application is really deployed.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/seagle2/

Comment: OK. You may try http://localhost:8080/seagle. I'm not sure that changing the context-root via 'web.xml' works in Glassfish.

Comment: The index.xhtml page is not defined as an index file. Does a GET on /seagle2/index.xhtml succeed?

Comment: @unwichtich For GlassFish, context root is configurable via glassfish-web.xml (not web.xml)